# How do you solve a simple simultaneous equation to get unkowns for a sinusoid (with no phase shift) given a couple of points?

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry, systems-of-equations, maxima-minima, interpolation

This is probably a very simple question, but I am struggling to find the answer.

Given:

\begin{equation}
y_1 = A \cos(\omega t_1)\\
y_2 = A \cos(\omega t_2)\\
y_3 = A \cos(\omega t_3)
\end{equation}

(I can go up to as much as $y_n = A \cos(\omega t_n)$. Using only $y_1$ and $y_2$ is also, probably, fine.)

So I know the $y's$ and $t's$. How do I find $A$ and $\omega$?

I, essentially, want to use that to compute the peak of a discrete signal I'm assuming is a cosine for a very short interval which includes that peak. So I thought if I can obtain the equation of the sinuoid then I can differentiate it, set it to $0$ and then solve for the $t$. That way I can obtain $t$ and $y$ at the maximum/peak.

Comment: You can have infinitely many solutions, even if you have any finite number of points, unless you have bounds for $A$ and $\omega$.

Comment: Formatting tip.  Your posts will look better and be easier to read if you write `\cos`, `\log` and so on for standard functions.  If the name you want isn't recognized, you can use `\operatorname{name}`

Comment: Thanks so much for the insight! I do have bounds for $A$ and $\omega$ as I am using this to locate the peaks of an autocorrelation function to determine fundamental frequency of an electrical grid. Anyway, for the signal I'm working with, my bound for $A$ is 4 and for $\omega$ it's 314. But I would be happier if I the solution can be expressed in terms of $A_{bound}$ and $\omega_{bound}$. Thanks for the formatting tip. I'll fix it right away.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that you have $n$ data points $(t_i,y_i)$, you want to adust $A$ and $\omega$ in order to minimize
$$\text{SSQ}=\frac12\sum_{i=1}^n \big[A \cos(\omega t_i)-y_i\big]^2$$ Computing the partial derivatives and setting them equal to $0$
$$\frac{\partial \text{ SSQ}}{\partial A}=\sum_{i=1}^n \cos(\omega t_i)\big[A \cos(\omega t_i)-y_i\big]=0\tag1$$
$$\frac{\partial \text{ SSQ}}{\partial \omega}=-A\sum_{i=1}^n t_i \sin (\omega  t_i)\big[A \cos(\omega t_i)-y_i\big]=0\tag2$$

From $(1)$
$$A=\frac {\sum_{i=1}^n y_i \cos(\omega t_i) } {\sum_{i=1}^n \cos^2(\omega t_i) }\tag 3$$ and plugging in $(2)$ you are left with an equation in $\omega$ which can write
$$\Big[\sum_{i=1}^n y_i \cos(\omega t_i)\Big]\Big[\sum_{i=1}^n t_i \sin(2\omega t_i)\Big]-2\Big[\sum_{i=1}^n \cos^2(\omega t_i)\Big] \Big[\sum_{i=1}^n t_iy_i \sin(\omega t_i)\Big]=0$$

**Example**

Let us use the following data
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
t & y\\
 13 & 49 \\
 14 & 90 \\
 15 & 114 \\
 16 & 124 \\
 17 & 112 \\
 18 & 85 \\
 19 & 42
\end{array}
\right)$$

I "know" that $0.3 \leq \omega \leq 0.5$. Just plotting the equation fot this range, the solution is close to $0.4$.

Starting Newton iterations, the path to solution is
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & \omega_n \\
 0 & 0.4000000000 \\
 1 & 0.3946667642 \\
 2 & 0.3945546651 \\
 3 & 0.3945546065
\end{array}
\right)$$

Plug the solution in $(3)$ to get $A=123.17165$. The recomputed values of the $y$'s are

$$\{49.87,89.33,115.1,123.1,112.3,84.14,43.10\}$$  and the peak is at $t=15.9248$

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{cases}
y_1 = A\cos(\omega t_1)\\
y_2 = A\cos(\omega t_2)\\
\end{cases}\tag{1}
$$
If you have two unknowns, $A, \omega$ you need only two equations.

If there is another equation, the risk is that the third is not compatible with the other two, like in this example
$$
\begin{cases}
a+b=10\\
a-b=4\\
2a+3b=1\\
\end{cases}
$$
first two equations have $a=7,b=3$ as result, but this doesn't satisfy the third equation. The system is *inconsistent*.

Back to $(1)$.

You get $A$ from the first equation
$A=\frac{y_1}{\cos\omega t_1}$ and plug it in the second:

$y_2=\frac{y_1}{\cos\omega t_1}\cos \omega t_2$

$y_2\cos\omega t_1-y_1\cos\omega t_2=0$

which can be solved with numerical methods once you have the actual values.

There is no formula to solve something like

$1.2 \cos (3.6 \omega)-0.75 \cos (2.7 \omega)=0$

Once you get $\omega$ you substitute and find $A$.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for this! May I please find out what you means by solving with numerical methods once you have the actual values. How do I go about doing that? I put the equation in Wolframalpha and while it gives me x, it doesn't give me the steps it used.